# Xcode - Start Volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, volume

I am making an app that blasts noises. I want to make the volume on the phone increase at the startup of the app.

What code should I add to the app?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have no programmatic access to change system volume, I imagine unless you're accessing private APIs, which essentially limits distribution of your app to jailbreak marketplaces, fundamentally diminishing the size of your target audience.

You can at least find out the current system volume utilizing the property [`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume] (docs linked)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/outputVolume), and notify the user that their volume is low, perhaps.